# Bootstrap Modal Does not work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a modal work but it just wont work.

This is my code: pastebin.com/ES17Dxkk

I followed everything on the bootstrap site but it just wont want to work.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have to load jQuery before bootstrap

Comment: Just a tip. To make a _good question_, add your code here and tell us whats not working.

Comment: Look at the pastebin, that's the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Bootstrap's javascript requires JQuery to be loaded. Add the following line before you import the bootstrap JavaScript:

```
<!-- Javascript Files -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```